# se ha producido el error "-2147417848 (80010108)"

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo un macro que me permita desbloquear celdas y dejar bloqueadas otras celdas cuando hago un cambio en una columna. El error me da cuando voy a hacer el delete `Sheets(S_Final).Protection.AllowEditRanges(j).Delete` he intentando poner un DoEvents antes y despues, pero me sigue fallando. Yo creo que se llena alguna "cola" del excel, ya que cuando le doy a depurar, y le vuelvo a ejecutar, no me da error.

Tengo que estar creando y borrando en la misma fila, porque depende de que opción elija me tiene que bloquear unas celdas y permitir otras. No se como quitar ese error

[image: Imagen del Error]

Otra cosa curiosa que veo es que si no tengo abierto el visual Basic, directamente se me cierra sin dar error.

Probando a quitar la parte de proteger del codigo y dejando la hoja desprotegida, ahora me sale otro error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Un saludo!

Dejo aqui el codigo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim numRango As Integer


If Target.Column = 9 Then 'Si La columna es la I vemos que texto tiene
    DESPROTEGER 'Desprotejo la pestaña para poder permitir la escritura de las celdas que no esten bloqueadas "B")

    numRango = Sheets(S_Final).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Count
    j = 1
    Do While j <= numRango
        If Split(Sheets(S_Final).Protection.AllowEditRanges(j).Title, " ")(2) = Target.Row Then 'Miro que la proteccion sea igual que la linea que estoy modificando
            Sheets(S_Final).Protection.AllowEditRanges(j).Delete ' Si es igual que la linea, borro la proteccion
            j = j - 1 ' Tengo que restarle porque le he quitado una proteccion por el medio
            numRango = numRango - 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    
    'En funcion de la observacion se bloquean unas celdas y se permiten otras
    For l = 16 To Sheets(S_Plan).Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row ' nos reccorremos todas las filas de la plantilla para ver que opcion se ha elegido
        If Sheets(S_Plan).Cells(l, 9) = Sheets(S_Final).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) Then 'cuando se haya elegido una opcion de la lista, avanzamos y empezamos a recorrernos las columnas
            For i = colDesde To colHasta 'nos recorremos todas las columnas y permitimos las que celdas que sean distintas de "B"
                If i = 14 Then 'Esta condicion es porque en 2. final no hay columna "N" asi que vamos a la siguiente columna
                    i = i + 1
                End If
                If Sheets(S_Plan).Cells(l, i) <> "B" Then 'aqui cambiar, en vez de ver si esta vacio, mirar la plantailla a ver si es un campo bloqueado
                    Sheets(S_Final).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Rango Fil " & Target.Row & " Col " & Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1), Range:=Range(Split(Sheets("2. Final ").Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1) & Target.Row), Password:=""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    
    If Cells(Target.Row, 16) <> "" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 21) = Cells(Target.Row, 16)
    End If
    
    If Cells(Target.Row, 18) <> "" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 22) = Cells(Target.Row, 18)
    End If
    PROTEGER
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: que mas información tiene el mensaje de error?

Comment: Buenos dias Nolberto, he editado la pregunta y he subido una imagen y debajo un coemntario. Gracias!

Comment: Resulta algo difícil porque hay mas cosas sucediendo fuera de ese código, asegúrese de que la hoja `S_Final` realmente este desprotegida para cuando se llega a la línea que da el error, me parece que por ese lado puede estar el problema.

Comment: Hmmm, puede ser que no le de tiempo a desproteger la hoja antes de hacer el delete? dejare la hoja desprotegida y ejecutare el codigo a ver si es eso. Gracias! te informare cuando lo tenga probado

Comment: He hecho la prueba desprotegiendo la hoja y comentando la accion de proteger y ahora se me cierra y me sale otro error. Locuelgo mas arriba